# The meaning of "closed by Maxwell's Equations"?

Tags: electromagnetism, terminology

I am reading some lecture notes (the context is the Vlasov–Landau equation but this is irrelevant for this question) and the phrase came up that the equation was "closed by Maxwell's Equations". A quick [Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22%20closed%20%20by%20%20Maxwell%E2%80%99sequations%20%22&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=w-l1WdrhAYmra4KQsOAD#safe=active&q=%22%20closed%20by%20Maxwell%27s%20Equations%22) shows me that this is quite a common phrasing. I can't, however, seem to find an explanation of what it actually means. Therefore my question is this:

**What does it mean for an equation to be closed by Maxwell's equations?**

Comment: Hi Q.S., I do believe context is relevant for this question. Do you think you could specify where you read that? Thanks!

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform The notes themselves arnt' publicly accessible. But the content is simply saying that  the Vlasov–Landau equation is closed by Maxwell's Equations.

Comment: +1 thanks for asking about this, questions like yours above help with the jargon I am supposed to know. I deleted my guess.

Comment: Are you sure the text says that the *equation* is closed, as opposed to saying that some differential form appearing in that equation is closed?

Comment: @WillO I am pretty sure it is referring to the equation. The wording in my previous comment is almost verbatim from the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We say that a system of equations is closed if it can be used (at least in principle) to uniquely solve for the unknowns. As an example, Laplace equation is not closed, but if you add appropriate boundary conditions (e.g. Dirichlet or Neumann) it becomes closed system. I think what is meant in the notes you are qutoing is that this Vlasov-Landau equation is not sufficient to solve for the unknonws (too many variables, too few equations), but you should combine it with Maxwell equations to obtain physical predictions.